# Pine Script modify MACD buying entry signal

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm new to pine script and have some trouble to add something specific to the MACD strategy:

```
//@version=4
strategy("MACD Strategy", overlay=true)
fastLength = input(12)
slowlength = input(26)
MACDLength = input(9)
MACD = ema(close, fastLength) - ema(close, slowlength)
aMACD = ema(MACD, MACDLength)
delta = MACD - aMACD
if (crossover(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdLE", strategy.long, comment="MacdLE")
if (crossunder(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
//plot(strategy.equity, title="equity", color=color.red, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_areabr)
```

Sell signal is going to stay the same but the buying signal is supposed to be a MACD crossover, however only if the parabolic sar stars are below the candles.

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

just to check, so you want to keep the sell signal as

```
if (crossunder(delta, 0))
    strategy.entry("MacdSE", strategy.short, comment="MacdSE")
```

are you happy with the above?

Next, do you wish to change the buy/long signal, to signal only when there is a MACD crossover AND the parabloc SAR is below the candle's lowest price?